# How can I use a promise to see if firebase auth is loaded?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

*Note: I am using react js and all my code is within a react component class.*

I want to check if someone is an admin, so I made this function:

```
makeDatabaseCall = () => {

    let userDB = this.props.firestore.collection('user');
    let queryUserDB = userDB.where('userIdentifier', '==', this.props.auth.uid).limit(1).get()

        .then(snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.docs[0].data().clearance)

            return (
            this.setState({
            clearance: snapshot.docs[0].data().clearance 
            })
            )
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        });
}
```

But I need to use this.props.auth.uid, so I need to wait until the auth is loaded.

I don't want to put this inside an if statement in my render() because that would make my code inefficient (it would keep checking forever).

How can I use the concept of promises to make an asynchronous call to firebase, see if the auth is loaded, and **then** run the function above?

Also here is my auth code:

````
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection: 'events',
        collection: "user"
     }
    ])
)(Dashboard)```
````

Comment: You really need to provide more info, for example, where do you load `auth`? Show the code being used in context. Also, FWIW, I don't fully understand why you think if you put code behind an `if` it would keep checking forever, by definition of an `if` statement, it would only check _if_ the condition is true.

Comment: well if it's in render() it would need to keep checking. I will add the other code. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

That's actually not the strategy you want to use.  You should use an [auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to receive a callback whenever the user signs in or out.  You can use this callback to determine exactly when a user is signed in, and get the UID for use in your query.  You probably don't want to try to convert this into a promise, because you are given no guarantee when a user actually takes this action in your app.  Your listener should kick off any queries (or send other signals using whatever frameworks you use, such as RxJS) as necessary when the user signs in.

Comment: how would I call this inside of a class?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You write code in the callback to react to the change in state as you see in the linked documentation.

Comment: well, I keep getting this error: TypeError: this.props.auth.onAuthStateChanged is not a function